# Scraping Facebook Video Length from URL

Tags: r, facebook, url, video, web-scraping

I have a list of URLs for videos on Facebook (one, for example: https://www.facebook.com/StudioCtv/videos/1314510761962662/) and I'm trying to scrape the length/duration of each video (i.e. 0:00, 1:32, 4:59, etc.). I need the data for analysis I'm doing in R but I'm open to different ways of approaching this. Is there a straightforward way to collect this information?

Comment: Don't scrape Facebook. Facebook doesn't allow that. Use the API

Comment: apologies for my ignorance, but what would be the best way to do that? that's good to know. I'm open to finding this information however I can most easily get it.

Comment: You can read about the API at https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create an app say Your_Video_app by going to https://developers.facebook.com/docs , then get a token for your app (your secret key) and authenticate yourself.

After that use RStudio or R , and get httr, RCurl, and RFacebook packages. Authenticate token using the Oauth. Next use getUser function or getLikes and you should be able to get details about your data.